# Oxidation state of iron ions in a unit cell

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox

[image]

> Consider UC (unit cell) for a cubic ionic lattice containing 4 oxide ions - what is the avg oxidation state for Fe ions in this lattice?

The four oxide ions create a -8 charge that must be counteracted by the iron ions. In a FCC unit cell, there are 3 total Fe ions per UC; therefore each ion must have a +8/3rds oxidation state.

Is this correct?

Comment: It's mixed oxide - average ox state is 8/3, but one center has +2 and two have +3.

Comment: Fe oxides are, in fact, notorious (famous?) for having mixed oxidation states.